# NSString scanning?

Tags: iphone

i am having NSString* str = @"1223.2212311";
i want to convert it as 1223.22(after floating point two chars),is it possible through NSString?i have to use NSScanner? any help please?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at NSNumberFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
NSString* str = @"1223.2212311";
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [str floatValue]];
```

Answer (score -1):

If the strings aren't going to be localized, you can just use `-[NSString floatValue]` to parse them.

Comment: Anything presented in the UI should be ready for localization. Your customers in France want to see a , symbol for the decimal. If you use NS numberFormatter you get that for free.

Comment: This is a question about *parsing* a string into a float, not displaying a float as a string.